# scrolling until last cel of uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, collectionview

I have a problem while scrolling my collectionView 
after choosing a cell, the last cell is not available for choosing 
[image: under this cell there is another cell but there is not any space for scrolling]

[image: unavailable last cell can not scroll to reach it]

```
   func changeViewSize(from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.transition(with: myCollection, duration: 0.5, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {() -> Void in
        let cell = self.myCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
        let cellCenter = CGPoint(x: cell.center.x, y: cell.center.y + 50)
        if cell.bounds.height == from {
            let sizee = CGRect(x: cell.center.x, y: cell.center.y, width: cell.frame.width, height: to)
            self.myCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.frame = sizee
            self.myCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.center = cellCenter
            for x in self.indexPathss {
                if x.row > indexPath.row {
                    print("this is cells")
                    print(self.myCollection.visibleCells)
                    let cell = self.myCollection.cellForItem(at: x)!
                    cell.center.y += 100
                }
            }
        }
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        print("finished animating of cell!!!")
    })
}
```

Comment: `cellForItem(at:)` should returns nil the the cell if not visible, do doing all the unwrap with `!`, that could strongly lead to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're changing cell sizes and positions manually. The `UICollectionView` won't be aware of these changes and therefore its size is not changing. The last cells simply move out of the visible area of the collection view.

I haven't done something like this before, but have a look at [`performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates). I'd try to reload the cell that you want to make bigger using that method. Your layout will have to supply the correct attributes, i.e. size.

From the screenshots it looks like maybe you could use a `UITableView` instead? If that's a possibility it might simplify things. It also has a `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` method, and the `UITableViewDelegate` would then have to provide the correct [heights for the rows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview).

Answer (score 0):

Because of spacing of cell we used collectionView and I think changing height of tableviewcell is easier than collectionviewcell if you have an idea for spacing of tablviewcell wi will be glad to have your idea.